# Ruby on Rails 7 - link_to helper question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a `Ruby on Rails 7` application. I am building a logic to delete multiple records on a page. Below are the details:

I have a page displaying list of Processes as shown below:

[image]

You can see that I have added checkboxes and want to provide a functionality where a user can click the checkboxes and then click a Delete link to delete all the selected records.

[image]

Below is the **View** code:

```
<% @operations.each do |operation| %>
<div class="card rounded-0">
  <div class="card-header">
  
  <%= check_box_tag "operation_ids[]", operation.id %> <b><%= operation.name %></b>
    
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p class = "fs-6 text-muted text-justify fw-light"><%= operation.process_description %></p>


      <p class = "fs-6 text-muted text-justify fw-light">Created: <%= operation.created_at.strftime("%d-%B-%Y") %></p>
    
      <hr>
    </blockquote>
    <br/>
    <%= link_to "Details", home_show_operation_path(id: operation.id), class: "btn btn-dark btn-sm rounded-0"%> </button>
    <%= link_to 'Delete operation', home_delete_operation_path(id: operation.id), method: :delete, data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-dark btn-sm rounded-0" %>


  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<%end%>
```

Below is the Route code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'tools/create'
  get 'tools/update'
  get 'home/homepage'
  get 'home/lightwave_users'
  post 'home/import_users'
  get 'home/operations'
  get 'home/tools'
  post 'home/update_tool_record'
  get 'home/show_operation'
  delete 'home/delete_operation/:id', to: 'home#delete_operation', as: :home_delete_operation
  delete 'home/delete_selected_operations'


  devise_for :users

  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root "home#homepage"

  # Below route is required for logout functionality.
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/sign_out' => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
end
```

Below is the controller method:

```
#Delete multiple operations.
  def delete_selected_operations
    @selected_operations = Operation.find(params[:operation_ids[]])
    #Array objects can be deleted one by one only.
    @selected_operations.each(&:destroy)
  end
```

Below is the link_to helper code:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Process", home_delete_selected_operations_path(operation_ids[]), data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

**Error**
When I select multiple records and click the "Delete Process" button, I see the following error.

```
undefined local variable or method `operation_ids' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000016b98>
```

I am unable to visualize and understand the reason for this error.

Comment: 1. The reason is literally you haven't defined this method or variable. It is more strange that you have this error only when click the link, but not when page is loading, are you sure? 2. You should collect all ids (for example with JS) and pass them as params. 3. `Operation.where(id: params[:operation_ids[]]).destroy_all` to delete all records

Comment: @mechnicov Thank for your response. Yes, you are right. This error comes up on page load itself.

Comment: A lot of your pain here is because you should be using a form and not a link. A form will do exactly what @mechnicov says even without any JS enhancement and as a rule whenever you're doing something which is not idempotent use a form instead.